# Why is the Cox-model X-year survival probability the baseline survival function at time X to the power exp(beta * x)?

Tags: survival, cox-model

As the the baseline survival function is different for each time-point, why does the above give you X-year survival probability?

I would have expected the calculation to be some kind of aggregation of results from from time 1:X.

Comment: "Survival risk" isn't a common term in survival analysis, do you mean "survival probability"?

Comment: Yes, thanks I am thinking about risk of death but talking about survival so got mixed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would have expected the calculation to be some kind of aggregation of results from from time 1:X.

The survival function *is* an aggregate. The survival function is the negative exponential of the *cumulative hazard function*:

$$S(t) = P(T > t) = \exp{(-H(t))}$$

where the $H(t) = \int_0^t h(s) ds$, $h(t)$ is the hazard.

The above is true in any survival model, including the Cox model. So when you use the baseline survival, you are implicitly using an "aggregated" calculation (the software handles it though).